# Populating a ComboBox from a table in a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to do something I thought would be very simple, but is currently completely baffling me.

Let's say I've got two tables.  One with a list of Owners in it (to maintain uniqueness).  The other has a list of items and their owner.  I want to have two datagrids:
1) the list of owners.
2) The list of items and their owner, where the owner is picked from a combobox.

The first of these was dead simple: Set up the table as a datasource, and drag it onto a WPF form.  Works just fine:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ownersViewSource}}" Name="ownersDataGrid" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ownerColumn1" Binding="{Binding Path=Owner}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The other part isn't working.  I'd have thought that this would work, but I'm clearly not getting it:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ownersViewSource}}" DisplayMemberPath="Owner" />
    </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

(Obviously, this is inside a DataGrid)

The problem is that this shows the list - but selecting the item from the combobox also changes the selected item in all other rows to be that item!

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Owner Choice" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ownerViewSource}}" DisplayMemberPath="Owner" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Owner}"  />
```

(The ItemsSource binds to one place, the SelectedItemBinding binds to the other.)